# Missing ProExtensionHost.framework unable to run Final Cut Workflow Extension

Tags: swift, macos, finalcut

My Final Cut Workflow extension has randomly started to output this error that it's missing the **ProExtensionHost.framework**.

I've attempted to clear the derived data, build folders, cleared Final Cut's cache, but nothing. I've even disabled Library Verification. An attempt at all the above steps and restarting my Mac. Finally, I uninstalled everything and reinstalled, but even past commits are running into the same error.

Has anyone ever run into this issue and resolved this?

Edit: Tried creating a new workflow project, and it looks like the FCPX Workflow Extension is missing.

Edit 2: More and more likely it's due to the missing FCPX workflow extension option in Xcode. Unsure how to add this back and why it went missing in the first place.

Edit 3: Reinstalled Final Cut. Looks like the previous git commits are working now, but the latest one is still having issues.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone ever runs into this issue the error itself is:

```
func activeSequenceChanged() {
    if let sequence = host?.timeline?.activeSequence {
        print(sequence.name)
    }
}
```

That function breaks the FCPX extension and of course Xcode spits out a completely unrelated error telling you it can't find ProExtension :D